# Angular evaluate expression when set as a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Say for instance you have the following:

```
    $scope.element =
            {
                html: '<a type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded m-r-sm"><i class="icon icon-user-unfollow"></i></a>',
                classExpression : " {{inactive == 'true' ? 'btn-success': 'btn-danger'}}",
            }
```

As you can see we have a veriable called `classExpression` which is the expression i wish to append to the element

```
 <span  ng-bind-html="element.html | trust" class="{{element.classExpression}}">Text in between<span>
```

However it doesnt evaluate it.

So my question how is this possible (if it is even possible)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7995/)

Updated my fiddle (it wasnt working)

Comment: Why not just use ng-class? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: try to use ng-class

Comment: @Wake cant seem to get ng-class to work either with the expression as a property of an object

Comment: remove {{ }} from your class expression

Comment: Because ng-class expects an expression and doesn't need {{ }}. You need to make element.classExpression a function and interpolate it as `element.classExpression()`.

Comment: @estus can you give me an example

Comment: Your fiddle not working.

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol ive updated my fiddle

Comment: @MarcRasmussen any particular reason you are having `classExpression ` as a string?

Comment: @PankajParkar No there is not i could be a function if that helps (however i would prefer a string but for reasons too complicated to explain here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say refactor your object to have following structure. I don't really encourage you to put expressions into `string`.

**HTML**

```
<span ng-bind-html="element.html" ng-class="element.classExpression[element.inactive]">
    Text in between
</span>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.element = {
    html: '<a type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded m-r-sm"><i class="icon icon-user-unfollow"></i></a>',
    classExpression: {
      'true': 'btn-success',
      'false': 'btn-danger'
    },
    inactive: 'true'
};
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/apje3j55/)

Comment: This works. However million dollar question how do you do it with other values than true / false ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen depending on situation you can anytime change the `keys` of your `classExpression` value

Comment: @gyc may I know what you meant to say? FYI, `ng-class` doesn't work with `{{}}` interpolation directive

Comment: @gyc have you check console..?

Comment: Yes, the bind-html doesn't work because it's unsafe (no ngSanitize) yours don't bind html either. Class expression works though

Comment: @gyc my friend.. even if it works I wouldn't recommend to use `ng-class` with `interpolation` even angular team is suggesting the same.. Read a [docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) please or else directly [look here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues).. My point is `Mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice`

Comment: @PankajParkar This will set the class on the outer element (the span) what if i want to set it it on the elementer ? :( (sorry for the 100 questions)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-class directly instead of binding it to the element expression? It will be re-evaluated whever your scope.inactive will change (or you could bind the inactive to your element.

e.g

```
<span  ng-bind-html="element.html | trust" ng-class="{'btn-success' : element.inactive, 'btn-danger' : !element.inactive}">Text in between<span>
```

In Angular 1.1.4 and newer you could also use the ternary operator

```
<span ng-class="element.inactive ? 'btn-success' : btn-danger">
```

Here assuming you put the inactive on your element binding. You could bind directly to your inactive (on scope instead).

Comment: Can you have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7995/ and tell me what ive done wrong ?

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle to use ng-class with evaluating your scope value instead of parsing the value in as "classExpression" - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8001/ - This works (try changing e.g. your inactive value to true / false and see the class changes along).

Comment: There's a couple of problems with your approach : if you would want binding you'd want an expression evaluating the scope digest. Here you're trying to bind set your class to an expression not beeing evaulated. If you're only interested in a one time binding (using the value) you could change your code. Simply use class="{{className}} and use normal turnary expression in your js code (and let className) be the actual class. I'd prefer using ng-class with an expression as in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `{{ }}` from your `'classExpression'` like as -

```
 classExpression : " inactive == 'true' ? 'btn-success': 'btn-danger'"
```

and also use `ng-class` like as -

```
ng-class="{{element.classExpression}}"
```

Comment: testing with the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7993/ doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: Your fiddlle is wrong. and also before down voting, please check properly at your end. i have checked it separately. and its working fine.

Comment: I did downvoted, the reason is interpolation would not work with `ng-class` directive..

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol didnt vote you down. However my fiddle should be working fine now if you check it again

Answer (score 0):

Possibly make your classExpression a function:

```
$scope.element =
        {
            html: '<a type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded m-r-sm"><i class="icon icon-user-unfollow"></i></a>',
            classExpression : function(){
                return $scope.inactive == 'true' ? 'btn-success': 'btn-danger';
            }
        }
```